# Pointcloud to LaserScan

Tags: ros, roslaunch, pointcloud-to-laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to use the pointcloud_to_laserscan node. I am publishing a pointcloud2 type file to the topic "cloud_pcl" and to fram "laser". How do I set up the roslaunch file? I've never done this before...

Thanks,
-Hunter A.

Launch File:

```
<launch>
<!-- Fake Laser -->
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/      CloudToScan openni_manager" respawn="true">
    
        <param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
        <!-- heights are in the (optical?) frame of the kinect -->
        <param name="min_height" value="-0.15"/>
        <param name="max_height" value="0.15"/>
        <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_pcl"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35489/pointcloud-to-laserscan/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the `turtlebot_bringup` [launch file](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/ee8b48e42178/turtlebot_bringup/kinect.launch) to see how it's done for the Turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-01**:
I added the launch file I am using. The cloud is being published to "/cloud_pcl". What do I need to adjust to make this thing work?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-01**:
I could also use a SLAM for pointclouds. Does one exist?